# How to query for records with an array of pairs of attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Product` model in my Rails app with multiple attributes including `item_id` and `batch`. If I want to get a single `Product`, I can use this:

```
Product.find_by(item_id: 'ITEM001', batch: `05-2019`)
```

But I what I have is an array of ['item_id', 'batch'], like this:

```
[
  ['ITEM001', '05-2019']
  ['ITEM001', '04-2019']
  ['ITEM002', '04-2019']
]
```

How do I get all the products that matches the attribute pairs in the array?

Product model uses `item_id` and `batch` as a composite key. A combinaion of those two attributes makes the product unique.

**Example Scenario**

Suppose I want only the following results out of the above mentioned records:

```
[
  ['ITEM001', '05-2019']
  ['ITEM002', '04-2019']
]
```

I thought about doing this:

```
Product.where(item_id: ['ITEM001', 'ITEM002'], batch: ['05-2019', '04-2019'])
```

by mapping `item_id` and `batch` into separate arrays. But this will give me all three items I mentioned at the top.

Comment: Can you post your model ? What all attributes it has?  Is this consist of an array which inturn has array of item_id and batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create raw SQL in the where condition based on the parameters

```
value_array = [
  ['ITEM001', '05-2019'],
  ['ITEM001', '04-2019'],
  ['ITEM002', '04-2019']
]


query = value_array.map { |ele| ele.join('\' AND batch = \'').prepend('item_id = \'') + '\'' }.join(' OR ')


Product.where(query)
```

Comment: I have more than 10k+values in the array. Will this work for that many values?

Comment: Yes, it should work. The performance will depend on the number records present in that table.

Answer (score -1):

Get all of the item_ids and batches and then make the query:

```
array = [['ITEM001', '05-2019'], ['ITEM001', '04-2019'], ['ITEM002', '03-2019']]

item_ids = array.map { |arr| arr.first } # ["ITEM001", "ITEM001", "ITEM002"]
batches = array.map { |arr| arr.last } # ["05-2019", "04-2019", "03-2019"]

Product.where(item_id: item_ids, batch: batches)
```

Comment: This gives me wrong results. I have updated the question with a sample scenario. Can you please check that as well?